# What is better, hitTestObject or self calculation?(Actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I mean what is better for performance using the object.hitTestObject or calculate the bounds like:

```
if(obj.x > obj2.x && obj.x < obj2.x + obj2.width &&
obj.y > obj2.y && obj.y < obj2.y + obj2.height)
{
    trace('spaceship damaged!!!');

}

//or using

if(obj.hitTestObject(obj2))
{

   trace('spaceship damaged by hitTestObject!!!');

}
```

what do you use in practice more? and what is more efficient? how much percent performance gives the self calculation? 20%? 40%? 60%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article gives you a good insight concerning your question

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/26/relative-performance-for-collision-detection-techniques-in-actionscript-3/

HitTest seems to be the fastest, which seems reasonable as I'd reckon Adobe's API would be optimized for the best performance possible.

[edit] as for SO answering, bitmapdata.com seems to be slightly faster than Will Kru.

Answer (score 1):

refer a following `performance comparsion article`:

[Relative performance for collision detection techniques in ActionScript 3](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/26/relative-performance-for-collision-detection-techniques-in-actionscript-3/)

[Strategies for optimizing collision detection with BitmapData.hitTest](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/25/strategies-for-optimizing-collision-detection-with-bitmapdata-hittest/)

your like question

[[AS3] hitTestObject performance question](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4-game-programming/topics/232237)